# git add . command - doesn't add changes

Tags: git

I'm newly at git and I tried to study this useful cvs.

But I pushed some project to the remote repository and I want to update state and push this changes.

before this I want to add all changes that are done.

But when I run `git add .` - it doesn't do nothing.

The status are the same as before I have run this command.

Here is more info:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~/workspace/NewYearGift$ git st
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .classpath
#   new file:   .project
#   new file:   .settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
#   new file:   .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
#   new file:   .settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
#   new file:   README.md
#   new file:   logs/new-year-gift.log
#   new file:   output/GiftList_1387287018363.xml
#   new file:   pom.xml
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/controller/GiftController.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/ItemGiftBuilder.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/ItemGiftParser.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/NewYearGift.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/Caramel.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/Chewy.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/DarkChocolate.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/DesertChocolate.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/Generator.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/Halva.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/MilkChokolate.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/PorousChocolate.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/Sweets.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/SweetsGenerator.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/Waffles.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/model/sweets/WhiteChocolate.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/view/Application.java
#   new file:   src/main/java/com/epam/lab/view/Main.java
#   new file:   src/main/resources/log4j.properties
#
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~/workspace/NewYearGift$ git add .
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~/workspace/NewYearGift$ git st
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .classpath
#   new file:   .project
#   new file:   .settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
// the same thing
```

I couldn't figure out why this happen?

It should add all changes, but it ignore all...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `git add .` worked as expected - it recorded your intent to add files of interest into index. But, in order to finalize your addition, you need to commit: use command `git commit`, which will create commit object, and you will be able to actually push your change using `git push`.

Note: you probably did not want to add files like `logs/new-year-gift.log` or `.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`. I would recommend to remove them from your list using `git reset`, like this:

```
git reset logs/ .settings/
```

and maybe create `.gitignore` with content like this:

```
.settings/
*.log
```

Comment: for `.gitignore` it only create file and write at new line every time?

Comment: You create `.gitignore` once (and commit it for good measure). You can keep adding file masks you want git to completely ignore into it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have added the files already. Git has a concept of a staging area (also called the "index"), which is where files are placed before being committed. So, a typical workflow would be:

1. Work on your code
2. Run `git add` to add files into the index.
3. Run `git commit` to actually commit the changes staged in the index into the repository.

This is useful for when you wish to selectively add things to your commit, piece by piece.